# Intellij IDEA: False positives on build

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij IDEA for work on a Java project.

I'm finding I get a lot of false positives when I build in Intellij, but only when there are other compilation errors - e.g. I've made a change and expect a number of compile errors, so I build to find all the errors. (In this instance, I changed a widely used interface, and want the compiler to catch the errors so that I know which implementations to fix.) In addition to some of these expected errors, Intellij reports hundreds of false positives (which makes it difficult to find the real errors - at present the compiler is showing only one genuine compile error each time, so I have to rebuild to find the next error...). These false compile errors are not highlighted - indeed, they are not real compile errors. (Nor do they appear if I compile via Maven.)

The most common error is 'cannot find symbol class [X]', despite that class often being in the same project.

I've tried:
- upgrading Intellij (from 10.5.1 to 10.5.2 to 11.0.1)
- invalidating and rebuilding caches
- restarting Intellij
...but all to no effect.

I've searched the [Intellij Bug Tracking board](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/dashboard), but haven't found any reference to this there, so wondered whether this is user error (if so, what settings do I need to change)?

Has anyone else experienced anything like this? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: I would call a false error message a *false negative*.  A *false positive* would be code which apparently compiles in IntelliJ but doesn't.  I have seen this from time to time and reported the bug to Jetbrains, but never enough to cause a problem.

Comment: @amaidment: I'm rarely leaving lots of classes in a state that do not compile but, indeed, I do see something similar (although maybe not identical) since, well, literally years.  For example on desktop apps, where I'm using IntelliJ's GUI builder, if I have only *one* class that doesn't compile and try to recompile everything, I'll get a **lot** of the following errors: *"... Form. Class to bind does not exist: ...View"*.  I think that basically I get this message for every single GUI built using IntelliJ's GUI builder.  Once again, as my projects typically compile, it's not an issue :-/

Comment: @user988052, congratulations. My projects are also normally compiling. Indeed, I don't want to be in a state where the code doesn't compile... but occassionally one has to make a change that could cause lots compile errors (as per my edit, in this case, by changing a widely used interface) - it's those real compile errors that I want to fix, but Intellij's spurious error reporting means it is only reporting one real error per build...

Comment: why are you changing interfaces manually and not using the automatic refactoring tools which would completely eliminate the human error

Comment: @Jarrod what are the automatic refactoring tools for interfaces/implementations in Intellij?

Answer (score 8):

This is probably too late to help you, but maybe it will help somebody else.  I had a similar problem.  IntelliJ complained that it couldn't find a symbol class, and the class it couldn't find had an icon with a little x in the upper left hand corner.  The x indicates that the class was excluded from compilation.  (I have no idea how that happened.)

To include the excluded file, access project settings, e.g., by clicking Ctrl+Alt+S.  Then you can modify the list found under Project Settings -> Compiler -> Excludes, to re-include the excluded file.

Comment: I would have continued for hours looking for the reason. Maybe I pressed accidentally the Alt key when shortcut-saving the file.

Comment: Under Mac OS you have to choose "Preferences" from the application menu and then select Compiler > Excludes.

Answer (score 3):

Such issue can be caused by incorrect project configuration, like when some module source directories are added to the dependencies as library roots. If you can't find a problem yourself, either contact support or file a bug to YouTrack with a sample project attached and the steps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add a link to where such bugs are posted? Are there similar bugs already posted?