# IntelliJ showing false positive errors

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, ide, false-positive

My project complains about a missing 'symbol'. All of the classes it claims are missing/do not exist do in fact exist, I've verified myself and they are all present. Additionally, building the code through the `javac` command still works, which leads me to believe IntelliJ is having some issues.

I've tried [Invalidate Caches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21528871/9091276), I've checked if any files are [being excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14445482/9091276). Both of these have not solved my issue.

For some background information, I am on Manjaro. Additionally, the was working earlier today. I then decided to download OpenJDK 11, test it out a bit, however it unfortunately did not work too well as I had expected with most of my java applications, and I was forced to remove it. After that, I've had this error and I can't find a way to solve it.

Edit: Not all classes are 'missing'. Only some specific classes are showing up as missing, and they are definitely there.

Comment: Move/rename [IDE folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) to start with the defaults, configure the JDK again for the project and see if it helps.

Comment: That does seem to have worked, though I wonder if a simple reimport would have worked